# Typescript importing a node module

Tags: typescript, node-modules, vuejs3

I am using vue 3 with typescript and trying to import `vue-context`.
I am getting an error `implicitly has an 'any' type` error.
The file exists in my node modules.
What update do I need to do to line `import  { VueContext } from "vue-context"`
to get it to work with typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install types for vue context. Try this.

npm i -D @types/vue-context

Comment: I get a Not Found 404 error when I try that. When I try npm i -D vue-context I get an response that package is up to date